# In the Halo universe, what is Fletcher's Syndrome?

Tags: halo

In the animated film *Halo: The Fall of Reach*, "Fletcher's Syndrome" is mentioned as a potential side-effect of the augmentation process.

Is there any source or material that says what this syndrome is, and what the effects of having it are? It doesn't sound pleasant.

Comment: Well, first you get a cardboard tube and a gerbil...

Comment: @Broklynite - No, that's Gere Syndrome.

Comment: @Richard this guy gets it at least

Comment: Given that there is no real "Fletcher's Syndrome", my guess is that a treatment that is supposed to result in "***Alteration of bioeletrical nerve transduction to shielded electronic transduction. 300% increase in subject reflexes***" is likely to lead to *substantial* neurological malfunction, ataxia, impairment and mental degradation.

Answer (score 3):

If you look through all the lore and the equivalence to real life, Fletcher Syndrome is a systemic failure of vitals in a long lasting and painful manner.

Symptoms: Cranial Hemorrhaging, Cardiac Hemorrhaging, Spasms in disconnected tissue, Complete Muscle Collapse, Sensory Deprivation, Digestive Tract Bloating, Malnutrition, and the lowering of the immune system.

There is no cure and presumably wouldn't have any due to the lack of ability to address so many situations at once.

Multiple organ dysfunction syndrome (MODS) is the less extreme, yet real life version of Fletcher Syndrome. Though it doesn't contain all of the symptoms, it does contain the most crucial symptoms of Total Organ Failure.

Comment: Which lore are you referring to?

Answer (score -1):

The other answers are in-universe correct, but it's worth noting that the name might be a nod-and-wink writer's joke from author Eric Nylund regarding the character of Jessica Fletcher in the TV series *Murder, She Wrote*. It's an old joke about a fictional disease that results in people you meet continuously getting murdered under mysterious circumstances...

> Fletcher’s Syndrome is a dangerous and potentially fatal disorder that affects main characters who are detectives or otherwise investigators of crime.  Symptoms of Fletcher’s Syndrome include, but are not limited to, someone being murdered while at a friend's dinner party, someone being murdered while on that weekend getaway that has been in planning for months, someone being murdered while at a class reunion or extracurricular club reunion, a long-estranged (or at least hasn’t been seen an a few years) relative being murdered and the affected being the main suspect, a celebrity who the affected either idolizes or is seeing live being murdered or suspected of murder, and pretty much any leisure or professional situation the affected may find him- or herself in resulting in or involving murder.
>
> <sub>[The Theater's Reader: Cliché Play: Fletcher's Syndrome](http://theatersreader.blogspot.com/2011/02/story-telling-cliches-1-fletchers.html)</sub>

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I took the liberty of including an excerpt from your link into your answer so that casual readers don't have to follow the link for an explanation.